# invite users to like a page and keep track of likers with php sdk / facebook api

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

Is there a way in facebook php sdk to

- invite friends to like a page
- the inviter will get points, if some one will like the page from his friends. ( if he invited him/her )

where i should be looking in the API doc , any clue ?

thanks

Answer (score 1):

No, it is not possible to invite a user to Like a page and then track that they've liked it.

If you've got access to the user's profile, you can see if the user has liked a particular page by requesting the `user_likes` permission and then making a call to:

`me/likes/23828249681`, i.e. `me/likes/{page_id}` to see if they liked the page.

If data is returned by the API, it means the user has Liked the page, and will tell you when they liked it in the `created_time` attribute.

Example of returned data, when user has Liked particular page:

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "category": "Actor/director", 
      "name": "Kaley Cuoco Sweeting", 
      "created_time": "2014-01-01T00:00:00+0000", 
      "id": "23828249681"
    }
  ], 
  "paging": {
    "next": "..."
  }
}
```